# Making a dynamic require in PHP

Tags: php, codeception

I am new to PHP but i've already built a size-able Codeception framework. I'm trying to optimize the process of requiring files. Can this be made dynamic?

```
# _bootstrap.php

require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../bdd/SmokeTest/LoginSteps.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../bdd/SmokeTest/LogoutSteps.php;
```

Is there a way to auto require_once files in the bdd directory with the string "Steps" in the filename?

Comment: sure, assign a variable to a string and concatenate it, as per your *(with the string "Steps" in the filename)*.

Comment: [Codeception Autoloading](https://codeception.com/docs/reference/Autoload)

Comment: fyi, you can just use `__DIR__`

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic"?

Comment: @EmilePels meaning I don't have to manually require every Steps.php file I create.

Comment: @e_mam106 As suggested, you should look into autoloading them. If you can not do that for some reason, you can always decide to create a new file that only requires the "steps" files, and require that from your other files.